# AttributeError: 'org.modelio.metamodel.impl.uml.behavior.activityMo' object has no attribute 'getOwnedNode'

Tags: python, jython, modelio

I'm using a script to find all paths in an `Activity Diagram`. To do it, I use `Modelio 4.0`.

I put the below script in a macro.

**Script**

```
## return first initial node in the selected activity
def getInitialPoint(act):
    for node in act.getOwnedNode():
        if isinstance(node, InitialNode):
            return node

## parcours activity nodes
def getPaths(currentPath, currentNode): 
    for outgoing in currentNode.getOutgoing():
        node = outgoing.getTarget()
        if isinstance(node, ActivityFinalNode):
            paths.append(currentPath)
            return;
        elif  isinstance(node, DecisionMergeNode):
            getPaths(currentPath, node)  
        else:           
            getPaths(currentPath + " - "  + node.getName(), node) 

 ##Init
init = getInitialPoint(elt)
currentPath = init.getName()
global paths
paths = []
getPaths(currentPath, init)

 ##Print founded paths
for p in paths:
    print p
```

**Error**

But when I launch the macro, I'm facing the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'org.modelio.metamodel.impl.diagrams.ActivityDiagra' object has no attribute 'getOwnedNode' in <script> at line number 20
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<script>", line 20, in <module>
File "<script>", line 3, in getInitialPoint
AttributeError: 'org.modelio.metamodel.impl.diagrams.ActivityDiagra' object has no attribute 'getOwnedNode'
```

Could you please help me to fix it please? Thank you.

Comment: What is `elt` ? Where is defined?

Comment: It is a value provided by modelio. This message is displayed in the console :`The following variables are bound:
 - session   : the opened session (IModelingSession )
 - elt       : the first selected model element or null (Element)
 - elements  : the selected model elements (Collection<Element>)
 - selection : the SWT selection (ISelection)
Use 'session.getModel().getModelRoots()' to get the roots of each work fragment.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, elt is the selected Element.
This script works if you launch it from an Activity Element and not a Activity Diagram.

Best,